# Как оценивается сложность цикла и рекурсии в алгоритме?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

поставлена задача, вычислить сложность алгоритма решения задачи... я решил используя цикл и рекурсию

К примеру дана функция

```
void simple(N) {
...
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    }
if (...) {
    simple(N);
   } 
}
```

какова будет сложность функции simple? может N*N?

Comment: мне кажется или конктерно в данном примере с циклом и сразу после него рекурсией функция будет выполняться бесконечно?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, я не дописал условие. но уже исправил

Comment: напишите условие внутри if и как оно меняется.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, значит от условия тоже зависит сложность... можете подсказать ресурсы где я мог почитать про оценку алгоритмов ?

Comment: @Malik *Томас Х. Кормен «Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ»*

Comment: @Nofate Спасибо)